# Would this be a reliable way to deal with rounding errors when multiplying floating point numbers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, rounding, multiplication

I am adding client-side sub-total calculations to my order page, so that the volume discount will show as the user makes selections.

I am finding that some of the calculations are off by one cent here or there. This wouldn't be a very big deal except for the fact that the total doesn't match the final total calculated server-side (in PHP).

I know that the rounding errors are an expected result when dealing with floating point numbers. For example, 149.95 * 0.15 = 22.492499999999996 and 149.95 * 0.30 = 44.98499999999999. The former rounds as desired, the latter does not.

I've searched on this topic and found a variety of discussions, but nothing that satisfactorily addresses the problem.

My current calculation is as follows:

```
discount = Math.round(price * factor * 100) / 100;
```

A common suggestion is to work in cents rather than fractions of dollars. However, this would require me to convert my starting numbers, round them, multiply them, round the result, and then convert it back.

Essentially:

```
discount = Math.round(Math.round(price * 100) * Math.round(factor * 100) / 100) / 100;
```

I was thinking of adding 0.0001 to the number before rounding. For example:

```
discount = Math.round(price * factor * 100 + 0.0001) / 100;
```

This works for the scenarios I've tried, but I am wondering about my logic. Will adding 0.0001 always be enough, and never too much, to force the desired rounding result?

Note: For my purposes here, I am only concerned with a single calculation per price (so not compounding the errors) and will never be displaying more than two decimal places.

**EDIT**: For example, I want to round the result of 149.95 * 0.30 to two decimal places and get 44.99. However, I get 44.98 because the actual result is 44.98499999999999 not 44.985. The error is not being introduced by the `/ 100`. It is happening before that.

Test:

```
alert(149.95 * 0.30); // yields 44.98499999999999
```

Thus:

```
alert(Math.round(149.95 * 0.30 * 100) / 100); // yields 44.98
```

The 44.98 is expected considering the actual result of the multiplication, but not desired since it is not what a user would expect (and differs from the PHP result).

**Solution**: I'm going to convert everything to integers to do my calculations. As the accepted answer points out, I can simplify my original conversion calculation somewhat. My idea of adding the 0.0001 is just a dirty hack. Best to use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Just don't use floats for money at all?

Comment: You have not specified the problem. You state that 44.984999… does not round as desired, but you do not state what it rounds to, what you desire to round it to, or how you are displaying the value. One possibility is that the `/ 100` in your rounding operation introduces a rounding error that produces a value you do not want, a subsequent conversion of that value for display shows a value you do not want. There may be ways to correct that, but you must supply more information.

Comment: @delnan What do you use instead? I'm grabbing the prices from the HTML which are displayed to the user in dollars and cents. I can *convert* them to cents, which is what I will end up doing, but I have to start with floats.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: You can try it yourself and you will see that is rounded downwards, while the correct result 44.985 should be rounded upwards usually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think adding a small amount will favor you, I guess there are cases where it is too much. Also it needs to be properly documented, otherwise one could see it as incorrect.

> working in cents […] would require me to convert my starting numbers, round them, multiply them, round the result, and then convert it back:
>
> `discount = Math.round(Math.round(price * 100) * Math.round(factor * 100) / 100) / 100;`

I think it should work as well to round afterwards only. However, you should first multiply the result so that the [significant digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) are the sum of the two sig digits from before, i.e. 2+2=4 decimal places in your example:

```
discount = Math.round(Math.round( (price * factor) * 10000) / 100) / 100;
```

Comment: Of course, I always document thoroughly anything that makes one go huh? And I would even document your solution as well because someone may come along later and think it can be simplified to the typical `Math.round(price * factor * 100) / 100`.

Comment: Are the extra parentheses necessary? Or would this be good: `discount = Math.round(Math.round(price * factor * 10000) / 100) / 100;`?

Comment: No, they were just for extra highlighting. The expression will be evaluated left-to-right without them as well.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a small amount to your numbers will not be very accurate.  You can try using a library to get better results: https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum.

Comment: That seems like overkill to calculate a few discounts. It's more code than my whole PHP application.

Comment: Yes it could be overkill; depends on how important it is for your calculations to be accurate. If you are doing discounting, even working with penny values could be wrong if the factor includes fractions of a percent.  Maybe good enough though.

Answer (score 1):

Bergi’s answer shows a solution. This answer shows a mathematical demonstration that it is correct. In the process, it also establishes some bound on how much error in the input is tolerable.

Your problem is this:

- You have a floating-point number, x, which already contains rounding errors. E.g., it is intended to represent 149.95 but actually contains 149.94999999999998863131622783839702606201171875.
- You want to multiply this floating-point number x by a discount value d.
- You want to know the result of the multiplication to the nearest penny, performed as if ideal mathematics were used with no errors.

Suppose we add two more assumptions:

- x always represents some exact number of cents. That is, it represents a number that has an exact number of hundredths, such as 149.95.
- The error in x is small, less than, say, .00004.
- The discount value d represents an integer percentage (that is, also an exact number of hundredths, such as .25 for 25%) and is in the interval [0%, 100%].
- The error is d is tiny, always the result of correct conversion of a decimal numeral with two digits after the decimal point to double-precision (64 bit) binary floating point.

Consider the value `x*d*10000`. Ideally, this would be an integer, since x and d are each ideally multiples of .01, so multiplying the ideal product of x and d by 10,000 produces an integer. Since the errors in x and d are small, then rounding `x*d*10000` to an integer will produce that ideal integer. E.g., instead of the ideal x and d, we have x and d plus small errors, x+e0 and d+e1, and we are computing (x+e0)•(d+e1)•10000 = (x•d+x•e1+d•e0+e0•e1)•10000. We have assumed that e1 is tiny, so the dominant error is d•e0•10000. We assumed e0, the error in x, is less than .00004, and d is at most 1 (100%), so d•e0•10000 is less than .4. This error, plus the tiny errors from e1, are not enough to change the rounding of `x*d*10000` from the ideal integer to some other integer. (This is because the error must be at least .5 to change how a result that should be an integer rounds. E.g., 3 plus an error of .5 would round to 4, but 3 plus .49999 would not.)

Thus, `Math.round(x*d*10000)` produces the integer desired. Then `Math.round(x*d*10000)/100` is an approximation of `x*d*100` that is accurate to much less than one cent, so rounding it, with `Math.round(Math.round(x*d*10000)/100)` produces exactly the number of cents desired. Finally, dividing that by 100 (to produce a number of dollars, with hundredths, instead of a number of cents, as an integer) produces a new rounding error, but the error is so small that, when the resulting value is correctly converted to decimal with two decimal digits, the correct value is displayed. (If further arithmetic is performed with this value, that might not remain true.)

We can see from the above that, if the error in x grows to .00005, this calculation can fail. Suppose the value of an order might grow to $100,000. The floating-point error in representing a value around 100,000 is at most 100,000•2<sup>-53</sup>. If somebody ordered one hundred thousand items with this error (they could not, since the items would have smaller individual prices than $100,000, so their errors would be smaller), and the prices were individually added up, performing one hundred thousand (minus one) additions adding one hundred thousand new errors, then we have almost two hundred thousand errors of at most 100,000•2<sup>-53</sup>, so the total error is at most 2•10<sup>5</sup>•10<sup>5</sup>•2<sup>-53</sup>, which is about .00000222. Therefore, this solution should work for normal orders.

Note that the solution requires reconsideration if the discount is not an integer percentage. For example, if the discount is stated as “one third” instead of 33%, then `x*d*10000` is not expected to be an integer.